# Id of list returned by slicing in Python

Tags: python

I read that slicing of list returns a new list with the contents of the original list.
While running the following code why am I seeing the same id for all the list returned by slicing. Can someone explain what is happening here.

```
list_4 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(id(list_4))
print(id(list_4[0:1]))
print(id(list_4[0:2]))
print(id(list_4[-1:]))
```

Output:

```
2812068811464
2812100759880
2812100759880
2812100759880
```

Comment: because `id` only guarantees a unique number *for the lifetime of the object*. IN each case here, your new list gets reclaimed immediately (CPython implementation detail) and the private heap is free to re-use that memory to allocate a new list (again, CPython implementation detail)

Answer (score 2):

Your slice got deleted before the next statement, so the new slice has the same `id`. If you keep the slice, the `id` is never the same:

```
>>> print(id(list_4[0:1]))
139887348117232
>>> print(id(list_4[0:2]))
139887348117232
>>> print(id(list_4[-1:]))
139887348117232
>>> b = list_4[0:1]
>>> c = list_4[0:2]
>>> id(b)
139887348117232
>>> id(c)
139887348207200
>>>
```